# labeling the diagonal dashed with $\beta_1 + \beta_2 + beta_3$ below it and tilted with it

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, labels, tikz-cd

Here is the code I have:

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] \arrow[dashed]{dr}{\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3}
     &[0.5em] D \arrow[d, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}"] \\
    B \arrow[r, "f'"']  
      & C \arrow[r] 
      & X
    \end{tikzcd}
    \end{document}
```

But I need to label the diagonal dashed with $\beta_1 + \beta_2 + beta_3$ below it and tilted with it.

Any help in that will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add option `swap` to direction of arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] \arrow[dashed, swap]{dr}{\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3}
     & [0.5em] D \arrow[d, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}"] \\
B \arrow[r, "f'"']
      & C \arrow[r]
           & X
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

However, result is also ugly as before:

[image]

You may consider to redesign your commutative diagram:

- make bigger distance between nodes,
- write label of the diagonal edge along it:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
 
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
A \ar[r] \ar[d] \arrow[dr, dashed, "\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3", sloped]
     &   D \ar[d, "{(\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3)}"] \\
B \ar[r, "f'" ']
      &   C \arrow[r]
          & X
    \end{tikzcd}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

I strongly suggest you to read `tikz-cd` package documentation to make more familiar with it. Also it is very good idea to use the same syntax in the whole diagram.

BTW, `'` has the same meaning as `swap`, which move edge label on opposite side of arrows (edge). Therefore you can write third line of the `tik-cd` code as `B \ar[r, "f'" swap]`.